# How do I set language of datetime axis in bokeh?

Tags: python, localization, locale, bokeh

I have trouble with setting language in which datetime axis is formatted in `bokeh`. According to [documentation](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/formatters.html), `DatetimeTickFormatter` produces time ticks *'according to the current locale'*. However, whatever locale I set in Python, I get a plot formatted in English:

```
# jupyter notebook
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'pl')

import random
from datetime import datetime, date
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.io import output_notebook
from bokeh.models.formatters import DatetimeTickFormatter

output_notebook()

x_values = [datetime(2018, i, 1) for i in range(6, 13)]
y_values = [random.normalvariate(0, 1) for i in range(6, 13)]

p = figure(plot_width=600, plot_height=300, 
           x_axis_type='datetime', title="test", 
           x_axis_label='x test', y_axis_label='y test')

p.line(
    x=x_values, 
    y=y_values
)

p.xaxis.formatter = DatetimeTickFormatter(months = '%B')

show(p)
```

[image]

If that's relevant, global system locale is set to `en-US`:

```
PS C:\Users\ppatrzyk> GET-WinSystemLocale

LCID             Name             DisplayName
----             ----             -----------
1033             en-US            English (United States)
```

I am working with plots in multiple languages so *I need to change `locale` on the fly*. Doing that through `locale.setlocale` has worked fine for me with both printing dates to console and with `matplotlib`. How can I set it in `bokeh` such that dates are formatted correctly?

**EDIT**:

The best workaround I got is to plot dates as numeric axis (unix timestamp) and then use `major_label_overrides` to replace ticks with correctly formatted dates obtained from python's `datetime.strftime()`. However, in this case zooming to ticks in between data points is broken, so **this is far from being a satisfactory solution**:

```
x_values = [datetime(2018, i, 1) for i in range(6, 13)]
y_values = [random.normalvariate(0, 1) for i in range(6, 13)]

x_values_timestamp = [int(el.timestamp()) for el in x_values]
x_values_labels = [el.strftime('%B') for el in x_values]

p = figure(plot_width=600, plot_height=300, title="test", 
           x_axis_label='x test', y_axis_label='y test')

p.xaxis.ticker = x_values_timestamp
p.xaxis.major_label_overrides = dict(zip(x_values_timestamp, x_values_labels))

p.line(
    x=x_values_timestamp, 
    y=y_values
)

show(p)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem as I wanted the dates be displayed in portuguese of Portugal (pt-PT).

I found out that bokeh uses the file `https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-2.4.2.min.js` to set the datetime language.

In my case, I wanted to generate standalone `.html` files, so I opted to set `mode = 'inline'` when exporting the file (`output_file('test.html', mode = 'inline')`) to embed the `.js` into the `.html`. But I assume that it should be possible to make the `.html` file load a custom `bokeh-2.4.2.min.js` by changing its path in the`.html` `<head></head>`.

To solve my problem, I edited the exported `.html` (edit the custom `.js` if you don't choose `mode = 'inline'`) and replaced the following strings:

```
find = 'locale:"en_US"'
replace = 'locale:"pt_PT"'

find = 'en_US:{date:"%m/%d/%Y",time24:"%I:%M:%S %p",time12:"%I:%M:%S %p",dateTime:"%a %d %b %Y %I:%M:%S %p %Z",meridiem:["AM","PM"],month:{abbrev:"Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec".split("|"),full:"January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December".split("|")},day:{abbrev:"Sun|Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat".split("|"),full:"Sunday|Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|Saturday".split("|")}}'
replace = 'pt_PT:{date:"%d/%m/%Y",time24:"%H:%M:%S",time12:"%I:%M:%S %p",dateTime:"%a %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %Z",meridiem:["AM","PM"],month:{abbrev:"Jan|Fev|Mar|Abr|Mai|Jun|Jul|Ago|Set|Out|Nov|Dez".split("|"),full:"Janeiro|Fevereiro|Março|Abril|Maio|Junho|Julho|Agosto|Setembro|Outubro|Novembro|Dezembro".split("|")},day:{abbrev:"Dom|Seg|Ter|Qua|Qui|Sex|Sáb".split("|"),full:"Domingo|Segunda-feira|Terça-feira|Quarta-feira|Quinta-feira|Sexta-feira|Sábado".split("|")}}'

find = 'u="Sunday|Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday|Saturday|year|month|day|hour|minute|second|millisecond"'
replace = 'u="Domingo|Segunda-feira|Terça-feira|Quarta-feira|Quinta-feira|Sexta-feira|Sábado|ano|mês|dia|hora|minuto|segundo|milissegundo"'
```

I hope this helps anyone facing this "issue".